# How to programmatically mouse move,click,right click and keypress, etc. in winform and wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

how to programmatically mouse move,click,right click and keypress etc in winform and wpf. please help me with code snippet if possible.

Comment: Replated but not an exact duplicate: [Injecting Mouse Input in WPF Applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371279)

Comment: Why? It may be easier to use the Accessibility stuff to do what you want.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you want to truly simulate input. In that case  `SendInput` is the way to go. From [this link](http://robrelyea.wordpress.com/2007/06/15/sendkeys-for-wpf/)

> PInvoke to SendInput – this is the
>   official way to simulate input. It
>   pushes the input through all of the
>   expected code paths, and is
>   indistinguishable from real input.

An easy way to use this is with [InputSimulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) at CodePlex. Adding a reference to InputSimulator.dll you can simulate keystrokes like

```
// Tab
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.TAB);
// Shift+Tab
InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.SHIFT, VirtualKeyCode.TAB);   
// etc.
```

---

However, **InputSimulator** doesn't support Mouse yet but here is a starter for a **MouseSimulator**. It only does **LeftClick** and **RightClick** so far but with the help of the following two links you could easily extent it with **MouseMove** etc.

- [pinvoke.net: sendinput (user32)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendinput)
- [How can I emulate mouse events in an application?](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=377394)

**MouseSimulator**

```
public class MouseSimulator
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, ref INPUT pInputs, int cbSize);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct INPUT
    {
        public SendInputEventType type;
        public MouseKeybdhardwareInputUnion mkhi;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct MouseKeybdhardwareInputUnion
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public MouseInputData mi;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public KEYBDINPUT ki;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public HARDWAREINPUT hi;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct KEYBDINPUT
    {
        public ushort wVk;
        public ushort wScan;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct HARDWAREINPUT
    {
        public int uMsg;
        public short wParamL;
        public short wParamH;
    }
    struct MouseInputData
    {
        public int dx;
        public int dy;
        public uint mouseData;
        public MouseEventFlags dwFlags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }
    [Flags]
    enum MouseEventFlags : uint
    {
        MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001,
        MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002,
        MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004,
        MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008,
        MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010,
        MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020,
        MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040,
        MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN = 0x0080,
        MOUSEEVENTF_XUP = 0x0100,
        MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800,
        MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK = 0x4000,
        MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000
    }
    enum SendInputEventType : int
    {
        InputMouse,
        InputKeyboard,
        InputHardware
    }

    public static void ClickLeftMouseButton()
    {
        INPUT mouseDownInput = new INPUT();
        mouseDownInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
        mouseDownInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseDownInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));

        INPUT mouseUpInput = new INPUT();
        mouseUpInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
        mouseUpInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseUpInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));
    }
    public static void ClickRightMouseButton()
    {
        INPUT mouseDownInput = new INPUT();
        mouseDownInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
        mouseDownInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseDownInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));

        INPUT mouseUpInput = new INPUT();
        mouseUpInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
        mouseUpInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseUpInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));
    }
}
```