# WPF simulated mouse click not as fast as actual click

Tags: c#, wpf, input, automation, pinvoke

I'm simulating mouse input on a WPF window using SendInput approach as suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5098968/986443).
Basically what I do for MouseDown is:

```
//Some data initialization e.g. determine where to click
....
SetCursorPos(x, y);

var inputMouseDown = new INPUT { Type = 0 };
inputMouseDown.Data.Mouse.Flags = 0x0002; // left button down

var inputs = new[] { inputMouseDown };
SendInput((uint)inputs.Length, inputs, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)));
```

and immediately the same with:

```
//Prepare as before
....

var inputMouseUp = new INPUT { Type = 0 };
inputMouseUp.Data.Mouse.Flags = 0x0004; // left button up

//Send input as before
....
```

When I use this code to click a WPF button it works as expected but with a delay I cannot explain:
I measured the time from **Mouse Up** until a desired result for both this technique and actually clicking the control. 
The Mouse Up detection was done using low-level mouse hooks.

In all my measurements it seems that WPF process faster (~200ms) physical mouse clicks then simulated ones.

I tried this hundreds of times with various tweaks (e.g. delay between down event and up event) but delta stayed the same.

What is the reason for this delay? how can this be resolved?

Comment: Fairly bizarre that there are 2 snippets.  What is in between?

Comment: Nothing, at most a sleep for keeping mouse button down for a specified interval

Comment: What on Earth does "at most" mean?  Don't put *anything* in between.  And don't bother at all when you can pass an INPUT[2].  And don't randomly click at an arbitrary location and hope you hit something.

Comment: This is not the question, I tried what you suggested also. The problem is not that it is not working, the problem is that it is slower than clicking actual mouse